# Reset array position in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want to reset the array index position after reaching its last index in a For cycle in python.

#### Example:

```
# Array 1
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
# string
string1 = "hello world here i am bla bla bla bla bla"
b = []

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Here I'm adding to a new array the odd of each letter in the string:

for each in string1:
    pass
    b.append(ord(each))

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Now I'm trying to subtract to each odd the number in the `b` array, 
# the value of the number in the same position of the `a` array.

c = []
x = 0
for number in b:
    pass
    c.append(b.index[x] - a.index[x])
    x = x + 1
```

The problem here is that I'll receive an `indexError` saying that `'a' list is out of range`.

That append because a list has 23 objects, and the b list has 41.
How do I reset the a index count to 0 when it reaches its last item, so the 24th letter will be 1 again and the 25th letter be 2 and so on.

I don't want to continue the array index, I want to reset it to the 1st index.

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed that my post isn't formatted on it's best way. Hope you can understand it.

Comment: `b.index[x]` is not valid syntax

Comment: use cycle() from itertools https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use as index the reminder of the division between `x` and `23` using `x % 23`:

```
print 1 % 23     # 1
print 22 % 23    # 22
print 23 % 23    # 0
```

So for example `a[x % 23]` will return the first element of `a` (the one with index `0`) when `x` is a multiple of `23`.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have `pass` in your for loops, you can also use either a [list comp](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) or [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
for each in string1:
    pass # not needed
    b.append(ord(each))
```

Using `map`:

```
 b = map(ord,string1)
```

Using a list comp:

```
[ord(x) for x in string1]
```

`a.index[x]` is not valid syntax it is `a.index(x)`

But better to use `enumerate` to get the index:

```
c = [b[ind % 23] - ele for ind, ele in enumerate(a)]
```